# how to get process end status in java?

Tags: java, process

I have run an external tool through `exce()` function in a separate command line console.

```
command = "cmd.exe /c start /min doxygen " + strDoxyfilePath;   
System.out.println("command : " + command);

//pass the command to execute
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I used this for read input stream:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
    (p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")); //read output of doxygen
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println("I M HERE: "+line);
}
```

But control doesn't  go inside while loop and I want to get proper signal at the process end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because of the `start` in your command. You are probably doing it to avoid a cmd window but I think you cannot not interact with the program then.

Try

```
command = "cmd.exe /c doxygen " + strDoxyfilePath;
```

Also, note that

- You also need to read the stderr (`p.getErrrorStream()`)
- `Runtime.exec` is not a great way to start a child process. `ProcessBuilder` is the newer and better way to do it.

Comment: if i remove that start from command then it will stuck somewhere between process . actually doxygen tool use to parse group of c code if c files are huge then we need separate cmd console.

Comment: First you should verify if you can get the streams from the child process by removing start by using a small set of files to doxygen. If that works then even for large number of files you need to take that approach.

Comment: i tried, for few files it work fine but for huge files it stuck. to remove this problem i used start keyword in command line.

Comment: If you use start then you will not be able to read the streams. By "stuck" if you mean that you are not able to read anymore from the stream it could be either because you are not also reading stderr or the program is waiting for some input. If you search for ProcessBuilder here you will likely get good information on how to manage a child process from a Java program.

Answer (score 1):

I think the classic [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) still explains it best.